# Identifying users at the transport layer

Tags: routing, tcp, transport-protocol

I'm building a router that uses machine learning to recognize certain network flows for bandwidth allocation and it has become apparent I will need to maintain a lookup table of users in the system. I will only have access to the data at the transport layer, and I'm unsure how to be certain who's who in a dynamic system (assuming the majority of the packet data will be encrypted).

Are there any conventional/well known ways to do this? I've been approaching this problem as a machine learning engineer, still a newbie in networking. I can think of a few ways to use behavioral biometrics on the network traffic, but that would be a very resource heavy way of solving the problem (and not necessarily very accurate).

Comment: Routing happens at layer-3, not layer-4 (the transport layer). IP packets will have the source and destination IP addresses, and I suppose you could look in the payload of the packets to see the transport address, assuming that the transport protocol has such (they don't all have addresses). Unfortunately, something like the actual user is above OSI layer-4, and that is explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: @RonMaupin I don't need to know anything about the actual user, I just need to keep a discrete value saying how important the traffic coming from that user is (lets say 1-10, 10 for CEO, 1 for intern) so I know how many security programs to forward the traffic to (level 10 might get 20 different packet scanners, level 1 might get 1-2). I guess my question can be boiled down to is how reliable is the source address for keeping track of users, or will I need to get more creative?

Comment: @RonMaupin Also, the device is being built to handle MPTCP, so I'll have access to layer-4 data as well.

Comment: You could statically assign addresses, or you could use DHCP reservations to guarantee who gets which address. This doesn't scale, and will problematic when hardware changes. You are trying to impose something on the routing which is not part of the existing layer-3 or layer-4 protocols. Although its not a real OSI layer, many people refer to business requirements as layer-8. It is something above OSI layer-4.

Answer (score 2):

A user can not be directly identified at the transport layer. The common ways firewalls handle this is by associating the IP address somehow with the user and then mapping any flows to a user based on source IP address. Of course this will fail if there are multiple users behind the same source IP, like in multi user systems (UNIX, Windows Terminal Server...) or if the source of the traffic is a network with NAT where multiple IP addresses are mapped to a single one.

For building the association between user and IP address various methods are typically used, like:

- having some kind of static mapping
- dynamic detection which user is logged in at a specific system by having some agent running on the system, checking against active directory or similar
- having a capture portal where the yet unknown user needs to login before he can access any outside resources